# How to compile with qt for raspberry

Tags: software-compilation, qtonpi

Is it possible to compile for Raspberry Pi using the Qt framework or is it possible to install the Qt creator on the actual Raspberry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a RPi Operating system dedicated to running Qt - it's called QtonPi.

[Here's what Qt have to say about it](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-RaspberryPi), and [here's what the RPi people have to say about it](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/tag/qtonpi).

The Qt website is somewhat more informative: you can download the source or an image, and see a lot of videos about it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.
http://qt-project.org/wiki/RaspberryPi , it worked for me.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackExchange. If you could pad out your answer with some of the information found in your link then it will improve it's usefulness drastically!