# Qt for Raspberry 2

Tags: qt

I saw many threads about setting up Qt on Rpi v.1. RPi 2 is using ARMv7 architecture so probably toolchain for ARMv6 won't work like described [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3486/how-to-compile-with-qt-for-raspberry)

Additionally I would like to compile from Windows, is there any suitable cross-compiler for it?

Answer (score 2):

Anything compiled for ARMv6 should work on the RPi2.

Raspbian is still based on ARMv6 and the tool chain I use to remotely develop for the Pi 2 is the one I use for earlier Pi models.

Comment: Did you develop from Linux or Windows?

Comment: Linux, but not Qt.  The point is that the existing Qt tools targeted for earlier Pi models will still work on the Pi 2.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like [Qt 4 is available](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/q/qt4-x11/) pre-compiled in Raspbian jessie, as is  [KDE 4](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/k/kde-runtime/), which uses it extensively.  So you should not have to build the whole thing unless you are trying to customize it.

WRT a windows cross-compiler, I don't use windows but for ARMv6 I use **crosstool-ng**, which is available for the Windows.  I'd guess you'd need **ming-gw** too.

Note that since ARMv7 cross-compilers are much easier to come by, you might try that.  I'm not sure if the resulting binaries will work on an ARMv6 userland, but as a guess they *might*.  They certainly work on a Pi 2 with an ARMv7 userland.

The current ARMv7 distros are Snappy Core Ubuntu and the [Fedora 21 remix](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/28253/5538).  Fedora, and I would presume Ubuntu, have all the Qt 4 and 5 binaries.

Answer (score 0):

I work with the same program QT on RPI1 and RPI2 cross compiled from my linux VM with QT creator, Anything compiled for ARMv6 should work ...

I use linux for cross compile with a specific toolchain for ARM : https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/tree/master/arm-bcm2708 (gcc-linaro)

You can consider to use Ming-GW or cygWin to compile this toolchain on Windows, some help here about the linaro toolchain : https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/tree/master/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/share/doc/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian or you can download directly a compiled version here : https://releases.linaro.org/14.04/components/toolchain/binaries/

I have used this method for cross compiling on linux : http://www.ics.com/blog/building-qt-and-qtwayland-raspberry-pi